# Dictionary of events (each value can hold several methods)

Tags: c#, events, dictionary, monogame

I've tried looking for an answer here in previous posts, but I didn't find one.
I'm doing a MonoGame game, and I decided I want to have a event based keyboard handler.

So the KeyboardHandler class is a singleton class,
And right now it has:
- delegate void KeyPressEventHandler()
- events of that delegate for the four arrow keys
- static instance of the class for singleton
- get method for that instance
- A while(true) thread method and a method that creates a thread that calls that method.

The thread method is just a while(true) that checks if a keypress of any of the the four arrow keys have been pressed and activates their respective event if needed.

I want to be able to create a dictionary of `<Keys, (event or whatever)>` so that I can for example:

```
void doSomething() { }
KeyboardHandler.Get().SubscribeToEvent(Keys.A, doSomething)
void SubscribeToEvent(Keys key, Action toSubscribe)
{
    this.KeypressHandler[key] += new KeypressEventHandler(tobSubscribe)
}
```

And a method that would handle firing these event handlers of course.

But How do I declare such a dictionary?

EDIT: eventually implemented here: https://github.com/gioragutt/training/blob/master/MonoGameFirst/MonoGameFirst/BaseGameClasses/KeyboardHandler.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare you dictionary as a `Dictionary<Keys, Action>`.  Then you just have to check whether your dictionary actually contains that key.  Remember that the standard [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a method that has 0 input arguments and does not return a value.  If you need, you could use one of the other Actions that accept a set number of input arguments.  Your code might resemble something like this:

Setup your dictionary:

```
var keyHandlers = new Dictionary<Keys, Action>(); 
keyHandlers.Add(Keys.Back, () => Console.WriteLine("Handler for backspace"));
keyHandlers.Add(Keys.Enter, () => {
    //some other statements, 
    //maybe set some class-level property 
    Console.WriteLine("Handler for enter ");
});
keyHandlers.Add(3, NameOfMethodThatMatchesActionDelegateSignature);
```

Then in the main event handler, check the dictionary and try to do stuff:

```
Action actionToDo;
bool actionRegistered = keyHandlers.TryGetValue(key, out actionToDo);
if (actionRegistered)
{
    actionToDo.Invoke();
}
```

[A demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u7TRyY) that uses ints to register the actions instead of the `Keys` enum.

Comment: Hey dude, thanks for the answer, I didn't realize you can put a delegate as a value in a dictionary. It worked wonders, so I managed to solve it on my own, but still thanks a lot.

Comment: Mind reviewing my piece of code here? https://github.com/gioragutt/training/blob/master/MonoGameFirst/MonoGameFirst/BaseGameClasses/KeyboardHandler.cs

Comment: @GioraGuttsait I'm not much into code review.  But if your code now works and you have some specific questions about it (like efficiency, scalability etc) you can ask a question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Make sure to read their on-topic guides, but that's a more appropriate place to ask.  You'll get more eyes from people actually dedicated to code review.

Comment: Thanks dude, didn't know that place existed